# Installing Kubeflow without cluster admin privileges

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I'd like to install Kubeflow under a large kubernetes cluster for which I'm a namespace admin, but not a cluster admin.

I've been following this related git issue:

https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/1915

The issue suggests that v0.6 may be providing this capability, but the git issue has not been updated recently. Now that v0.6 is released I'm trying to track down whether this is now possible, and if so how to go about installing Kubeflow under a namespace without cluster admin privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v0.6 supports multi-user profiles which allow non-admin users to manage resources in their own namespaces, but the initial installation still requires cluster admin privileges.

Also replied on the GitHub issue.